# C++/CX and CString

Tags: atl, c++-cx

How can I use ATL classes (strings, collections, IPC, files and I/O, regexps, etc) in a C++/CX component?

For strings and collections STL is functionally more or less equivalent (they just usually work slower, and sometimes require more lines of code for simple tasks), however for the rest of areas STL has nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  You are listing too many things that you are not allowed to do in a Store app.  ATL is out.

Comment: IPC is out too, except when talking to winrt apps in the same package

Comment: IPC is not out.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx#threads_and_synchronization
And CComAutoCriticalSection/CComCritSecLock classes is very often the best way to synchronize resource access when doing native-code development.